# Accessing Pod through kubedns without expose as service

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-pod, kube-dns

I am trying to test inter-pod communication without expose as service.
I have read that a pod does have FQDN in kubedns.
[kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Its default should be (A Record)
metadata_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local
or
hostname.subdomain.namespace.svc.cluster.local

But I tried both with curl and nslookup. All failed. The service is healthy, I could curl it with pod IP (172.17.0.5)

> curl: (6) could not resolve host
>   nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolved

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a service with type `ClusterIP` for this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
```

It does not expose your pod outside the cluster. Note that this is default service type and you can omit specifying it.

Then query the serivce like:

```
curl http://my-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

This approach is better than using pod DNS directly for 2 reasons:

- you don't need to know the exact pod name (e.g. `name-id`)
- in this case you can run multiple pods behind the service and it will load-balance requests. Or just run one and it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> If there exists a headless service in the same namespace as the pod
>   and with the same name as the subdomain, the cluster’s KubeDNS Server
>   also returns an A record for the Pod’s fully qualified hostname. For
>   example, given a Pod with the hostname set to “busybox-1” and the
>   subdomain set to “default-subdomain”, and a headless Service named
>   “default-subdomain” in the same namespace, the pod will see its own
>   FQDN as “busybox-1.default-subdomain.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local”.

So in your case you need to define subdomain for pod and create [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) with the same name which points to pods.